# Extracting specific rows from tab delimited text file (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin

I need to generate a Cygwin script to pull out specific lines from a large tab delimited text file

For example:

```
chr1    184548974   184549885   SETDB1  436
chr1    226492354   226492784   CTCF    149
chr1    243269283   243269767   SETDB1  135
chr1    243269304   243269644   CHD2    239
chr1    243269306   243269746   CBX3    376
chr1    1048502     1049386     KAP1    380
chr1    2097139     2097389     TEAD4   209
chr1    9436759     9437223     POLR2A  169
chr1    9437031     9437357     NR3C1   542
chr1    9437111     9437327     CTCF    128
chr1    19922758    19923238    CHD1    277
chr1    19922759    19923079    JUND    177
```

And pulling out rows where the third column contains "CHD2"

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the rows that contains "CHD2" with the grep command:

```
$ grep -w CHD2 example.txt
chr1    243269304   243269644   CHD2    239

$ grep CH example.txt
chr1    243269304   243269644   CHD2    239
chr1    19922758    19923238    CHD1    277
```